# Problem relating to ratios and escribed circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If $I_1$ and $I_2$ and $I_3$ be the centres of the escribed circles of $\triangle ABC$ and if $R_1$, $R_2$ and  $R_3$ are radius of the  circles inscribed in the triangles $\triangle BI_1C , \triangle AI_2C, \triangle AI_3B $, then prove that

$$R_1 : R_2 : R_3 =\sin(A/2):\sin(B/2):\sin(C/2).$$

I got $$ R_3 = 8R\sin(C/2) \cos(A/2)\cos(B/2)\cos(C/2) $$
But I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I tried to post it using latex syntax but failed to do that...can anyone tell me where is the latex option??

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for writing math on the site.

Comment: In your edit you replaced S with C, so what role does the circumcentre now play?

Comment: @G-man _no role does the circumcentre play_.......the question is printed wrong in sl loney book.....i corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the circumradius of $\Delta ABC$ and $r_a, r_b, r_c$ be the ex-radii of $\Delta ABC$ opposite to vertices $A, B, C$. Next, it is easy to observe that $$\Delta I_{A}BC \sim \Delta AI_{B}C \sim \Delta ABI_{C}.$$
$$\therefore \boxed{\frac{R_1}{I_{A}B}=\frac{R_2}{AI_{B}}=\frac{R_3}{AB}}. \;\;\; {(1)}$$
Now, note that
\begin{align*}
I_{A}B &= \frac{r_a}{\cos{\frac{B}{2}}} \\
&= \frac{4R\sin{\frac{A}{2}}\cos{\frac{B}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}}{\cos{\frac{B}{2}}} \\
&= 4R\sin{\frac{A}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have
\begin{align*}
AI_{B}&= \frac{r_b}{\cos{\frac{A}{2}}} \\
&= \frac{4R\cos{\frac{A}{2}}\sin{\frac{B}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}}{\cos{\frac{A}{2}}} \\
&= 4R\sin{\frac{B}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}.
\end{align*}
And the extended Law of Sines yields us
$$ AB = c = 2R\sin{C} = 4R\sin{\frac{C}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}.$$
Putting these into $(1)$, we obtain
$$\frac{R_1}{4R\sin{\frac{A}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}}=\frac{R_2}{4R\sin{\frac{B}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}}=\frac{R_3}{4R\sin{\frac{C}{2}}\cos{\frac{C}{2}}}.$$
$$\text{i.e.} \;\; \boxed{\frac{R_1}{\sin{\frac{A}{2}}}=\frac{R_2}{\sin{\frac{B}{2}}}=\frac{R_3}{\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}}.$$
$QED.$

Comment: This answer is AI-Generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in the question. The given result does not hold for the inscribed circles in those triangles but for the circumcircles.

It's really simple actually. Just draw $\triangle ABC$ and all its exterior and interior angle bisectors. Let the exterior ones meet at $I_1,I_2$ and $I_3$ .  Doing some angle chasing you'll find that $\angle BI_1C=90^{\circ}-\frac A2$. Now if $R_1$ is the circumradius of $\triangle BI_1C$ then according to the sine law:$$R_1=\frac{BC}{2\sin\angle BI_1C}=\frac{a}{2\cos \frac A2}$$.

Also we know that $a=2R\sin A$ so just apply that in that to finally get $R_1=2R\sin \frac A 2$. After that there's not much left to  do.

Comment: $R_1$ is the inradius of $\Delta BI_1C, $ not the circumradius. Although, your proof is correct.